# An argument of type `ark_ec::short_weierstrass::Affine<BandersnatchConfig>` is missing

Tags: substrate-node-template, parachain

I wanna to build a parachain to run it localy .

The rust version I am using is : `rustc 1.72.0 (5680fa18f 2023-08-23)`

But when  I run the command : `cargo build --release` it show me this error :

```js
    Error[E0061]: this function takes 3 arguments but 2 arguments were supplied
      --> /home/kianoush/.cargo/git/checkouts/ring-vrf-fa8519651343a7ee/c86ebd4/bandersnatch_vrfs/src/ring.rs:34:5
       |
    34 |     PiopParams::setup(domain, &mut rng)
       |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^------------------ an argument of type `ark_ec::short_weierstrass::Affine<BandersnatchConfig>` is missing
       |
    note: expected `Affine<BandersnatchConfig>`, found `&mut ChaCha20Rng`
      --> /home/kianoush/.cargo/git/checkouts/ring-vrf-fa8519651343a7ee/c86ebd4/bandersnatch_vrfs/src/ring.rs:34:31
       |
    34 |     PiopParams::setup(domain, &mut rng)
       |                               ^^^^^^^^
       = note:         expected struct `ark_ec::short_weierstrass::Affine<BandersnatchConfig>`
               found mutable reference `&mut ChaCha20Rng`
    note: associated function defined here
      --> /home/kianoush/.cargo/git/checkouts/ring-proof-e9e49c3c86c409a2/8657210/ring/src/piop/params.rs:31:12
       |
    31 |     pub fn setup(domain: Domain<F>, h: Affine<Curve>, seed: Affine<Curve>) -> Self {
       |            ^^^^^
    help: provide the argument
       |
    34 |     PiopParams::setup(domain, /* ark_ec::short_weierstrass::Affine<BandersnatchConfig> */, /* ark_ec::short_weierstrass::Affine<BandersnatchConfig> */)
       |                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
    For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0061`.
    error: could not compile `bandersnatch_vrfs` (lib) due to previous error
    warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

**how can i sovle this problem ?**

Comment: Got the very same error when I did a new compile

Comment: Same here. I'm pulling my hair on this one, cannot seem to find the source of this problem, since the `polkadot` repo compiles fine. I have the exact same section about `bandersnatch_vrfs` in `Cargo.lock`, but it still fails.

Answer (score 1):

After spending a bit of time on it, I ended up finding the source of the problem: the offending crate `bandersnatch_vrfs` pulls `ring-proof` from a github repo, and for some reason it pulls a wrong version sometimes.

I checked the version in `Cargo.lock` from the archived polkadot repo (in my case, I build on top of the archived v1, before the migration to the monorepo), and copy/pasted the correct hash for `ring-proof` in my `Cargo.lock` where needed:

```
source = "git+https://github.com/w3f/ring-proof#0e948f3c28cbacecdd3020403c4841c0eb339213"
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same when mixing dependencies from the archived substrate repo and polkadot-sdk, you fix worked! Curious if you have found a more long lasting solution?

Comment: I think there is a fix you can use from their new monorepo, but I don't know which one exactly.